# Can't get a voice channel in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

```
    import os
    from discord.ext import commands
    
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='~')
    
    for fileName in os.listdir('cogs'):
        if fileName.endswith('.py') and fileName != '__init__.py':
            bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{fileName[:-3]}')
    bot.run(* TOKEN * )
```

The problem is on the code below:

```
    import discord
        from discord.ext import commands
        
        class MoveMembers(commands.Cog):
            def __init__(self, bot):
                self.bot = bot
                self.channel_to_move= discord.Client().get_channel(* channel ID *)
        
        
            @commands.command()
            async def send_to_channel(self, ctx, *members: discord.Member):
                for member in members:
                    if member.voice:
                        print(type(self.channel_to_move))
                        await member.move_to(self.channel_to_move)
                await ctx.send('message recieved')

            def setup(bot):
                bot.add_cog(MoveMembers(bot))
```

The point of this function is to move one or more memebers that have been referenced to a specefic voice chanel.

example: "~send_to_channel @person"

The function is called but for some reason "discord.Client().get_channel(* channel ID *)" doesn't return a voice channel, or any channel at that. I've read the documentation and some other answers in stack overflow but I can't figure out what is wrong...

**** EDIT ****
Also does anyone know why this code doesn't work:

```
def move_rights():
    def predicate(ctx):
        return commands.check_any(commands.is_owner(), 
                    commands.has_role("Move Rights"))
    return commands.check(predicate)



    @commands.command()
    @move_rights()
    async def send_to_gulag(self, ctx, *members: discord.Member):
        for member in members:
            if member.voice:
                await member.move_to(self.gulag)
        await ctx.send('message recieved')
```

Everyone can use this command so I don't know if the "move_rights()" functions returns always "true" or if just didn't implement it right. (The code is part of the code in the original question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `self.channel_to_move= discord.Client().get_channel(* channel ID *)` you're not supposed to refer to the class itself, but to the instance

```py
self.channel_to_move = self.bot.get_channel(* channel ID *)
```

It's important to know the difference between classes and instances

Comment: Thanks. I am not that familiar with Python but it seemed like the best lengauge to use to build the bot I needed for discord

Comment: discord.py is not supposed to be used by beginners, you're gonna have to learn more python or otherwise you'll meet a lot of bumps like this one.

Comment: I know. I'm have some familiarity with programing, just not with python. I usually take the time to learn a language before I try to start a project with it but I just needed to make a specific discord bot and all the community support seem to be aimed in bots written in python or node.js. So I took a shot at discord.py...